# Why does WCF return code 400 when content-type:application/xml header is present?

Tags: xml, wcf

I have a REST WCF service that is returning a Bad Request (400) response when the content-type:application/xml header is included in the request.  When I remove that header, the service responds correctly.

Service definition:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/methodName", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    XElement MethodName(Stream stream);
}
```

Endpoint configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding"
          name="webHttpBinding" contract="IRestService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The payload is valid XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to set up a `WebContentTypeMapper` in the endpoint - see more details in the post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx. You can add it either programmatically (as shown in the post), or using the `contentTypeMapper` attribute in the `<bindings>/<webHttpBinding>/<binding>` element.